# How to assign rest/ break intervals to a binary workshift timetable matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

circshift function, simple indexing of the rows/columns for each employee,...?
This is required to optimize a model. build in accurate real time runs.

The binary matrix is for 16 employees vs available half hour[2x24] slots.
The intention is for mat-lab to proffer a better (optimized) 16 by 48 matrix with other constraints, but adding the rest assignment in with this is a real challenge.

1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1
0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0

Thanks for attempting... :)

Comment: A challenge made all the more difficult by the fact that we have no idea what the constraints are.

Comment: Its a kind of knapsack problem, combinatorial optimization type. ignore the binary approach, the idea is to fit in work patterns with breaks  [see the (1)s with a (0) interval at two places], for about 14 workers (rows). into a 48 hr shift (see columns) with a specified minimum number per column. so problem/challenge is to find a way to capture the different patterns into MILP optimization on matlab with other constraints,.... details on what to do, will do